# IntelliJ IDE - cannot run Maven from terminal inside IDE (path is set)

Tags: bash, maven, intellij-idea

last week I got new laptop from company so I had to do new installation from scratch.
I installed my JDK, Maven, git bash and IDE, configured environment variables for MAVEN_HOME and JAVA_HOME... added them to Path with for example: %JAVA_HOME%\bin and same for maven.

Both JDK and Maven work perfectly fine with cmd and git bash or even with maven plugin in IntelliJ.
But if i want to open terminal inside of IDE and run some maven command it will give me mvn not found error.

I use /wanna use git bash, but it gives same error for cmd inside of IDE as well.

I've checked terminal system environemtns setting in IDE and I can find MAVEN_HOME inside and I even tried to add M2_HOME but error is the same (I do reset terminal after every change).

Also, in git bash if I write echo $PATH it will return me my variables as it can be seen here:
/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/user.name/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:
/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:%JAVA_H
OME%/bin:%MAVEN_HOME%/bin:/cmd:/c/Users/prese/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/c/Program Files/herok
u/bin

I never had an issue like this as usually all I had to do after installig java/maven and git bash was to change default terminal in IDE to git bash.... and that's it.
But something is different this time around.

Please do share what can I do and/or try.

EDIT:
If I write:
export PATH=$PATH:/c/Program\ Files/Apache\ Maven/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin

This will set maven and it will work... but only for this instance of terminal... new instace and session will not have it

Comment: Probably IDEA was not able to load PATH environment correctly. Try to put MAVEN_HOME to the top of the PATH, and restart IDEA.

Comment: Do not use MAVEN_HOME or M2_HOME etc. only put the entry into PATH `.../apache-maven-3.6.3/bin` (apart from that use a more recent version of Maven)...

Comment: @EgorKlepikov tnx for advice, tried and issue is still the same

Comment: @khmarbaise tnx for trying to help, I tried adding just a path, but issue remains.... I use 3.6.3 because it's company rule, so there is no choice in maven versions... besides, worked like a charm on older machine

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? I'm not joking, environment variables are read on startup.

Comment: @Dropout yeah, I tried that one probably the most :D ....